# jquery get variable from script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have such code:

```
<body>
  <script>
    window.nix = window.nix || {} ;
    nix.falkorCache = 1;
   </script>
...
```

I want to get `nix` variable with jQuery.

How can I access it?

Comment: How are you trying to access it and where ? Please share the code.

Comment: Please provide more context.  This sounds like a very basic JavaScript question which you already know the answer to (access variable using `nix` or `window.nix`), there is nothing jquery-specific about it.

Comment: Guys, when I am trying to access `window.nix.falkorCache` I see `Cannot read property 'falkorCache' of undefined`

Comment: Updated the question. The `nix.falkorCache` creates after the page load. Can it be the problem with trying to access it?

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote it, it should work. Anything assigned to `window` can be accessed as if it were a top-level value, i.e.,:

```
console.log(nix.falkorCache); // should work
```

If it's telling your that `nix` is undefined, the most likely culprit is that you are trying to access it before it is there.

In your HTML, that segment of code should be above any code that tries to access it, i.e.:

```
<body>
  <script>
    console.log(nix.falkorCache); // bad
  </script>
  <script>
    window.nix = window.nix || {};
    nix.falkorCache = 1;
  </script>
  <script>
    console.log(nix.falkorCache); // good
  </script>
```

That's the most likely culprit for your problem is just having it in the wrong order. If you're pulling in a `<script>` tag, you should put it at the bottom of your `body` element.

If that doesn't work, a few less likely culprits are:

- Ensure you aren't accidentally setting `nix` to `null` or `undefined` in between the two.
- Ensure you aren't trying to run the other code in an `<iframe>` or something.
- Ensure that you don't just have a simple typo somewhere.

Comment: Thanks. But the order is fine. The only problem that `window.nix = window.nix || {}; nix.falkorCache = 1;` creates after the page load. Could it be the reason why the variable is not accecable?

Comment: @KirMazur I'm not sure what you mean by after the page load. If your page refreshes, all data is lost and it all has to be created. Otherwise, it's all about the order. If it is created after it is tried to access, that's no good. Can you update your answer with a more complete example of your call?